# Angular trigger multiple http calls for each table row with data coming from ng store state

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on Angular project using ngrx store.
I have the following code to show my list of courses :

```
export interface CourseItem
      {
        id: number,
        name: string;
      }
    
    export interface State {
        readonly courses: CourseItem[];
    }



getAllCoursesEffect : Observable<CourseActions> = createEffect(

    () => this.effectActions.pipe(

     ofType(CourseActionsType.GET_ALL_COURSES),

     mergeMap((action)=>{

        return this.courseService.getAllCourses()
            .pipe(
                map((courses) => new GetAllCoursesActionSuccess(courses)),
                catchError((err)=> of(new GetAllCoursesActionError(err.message)) )
            )
     }) 
    )
)

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.courseItems$ = this.store.select((store) => store.course);
}

    <table class="table table-hover" >
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Meta data</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let course of courseItems$ | async">
              <td>{{course.id}}</td>
              <td>{{course.name}}</td>
              <td>here i want to show course description coming from external API</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

my issue is that after showing my courses in the table I want to trigger an API Http call by course ID to get additional information for each course and then show the data in the last column.
do you have any idea how to integrate these Http calls correctly with my ng store logic and without performance impact?
PS : my table will show only 10-20 max rows
thanks.

Comment: you are using ngrx. just load the courses and trigger the data enrichment after they are loaded with a reducer that would enrich every row with the corresponsing data

Comment: @Andrei thanks for your sugesstion. do you have any code suggestion please

Comment: from this point the question looks like you are asking to implement your task for you so it is done instead of teach you and anyone who searches for the same problem

Comment: @Andrei it's not the first time when someone ask for a code snipet here i didn't ask you to the job for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I never used ngrx so maybe there is a better way to do this, but this would be my approach:

```js
this.courseItems$ = this.store.select((store) => store.course).pipe(
  tap(courseItems => courseItems.forEach(course => 
    course.additionalInfo$ = this.myService.getAdditionalInfo(course.id)
  ))
);
```

in your html:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let course of courseItems$ | async">
  <td>{{course.id}}</td>
  <td>{{course.name}}</td>
  <td>{{course.additionalInfo$ | async}}
    <ng-container *ngIf="(course.additionalInfo$ | async) as additionalInfo">
      {{additionalInfo.description}}
    </ng-container>
  </td>
</tr>
```